# How to remove or hide loaded stl in three.js

Tags: three.js

How remove of hide loaded.load three.js according to the condition for example id the door condition = 0, if will load the flame.stl and reverse

function checkDoorStatus(isDoorOpen, prevIsDoorOpen){

```
                if ( isDoorOpen == 1)
                {

                    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                    loader.load( 'model/panic.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xa80306, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );    
                    mesh.position.set( 0.145, -0.3, -0.29);
                    mesh.rotation.set( 0 , 0, Math.PI / 2 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 0.05, 0.05, 0.05);
                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                    scene.add( mesh );
                    } );

                    //console.log("Panic 1");

                }
                else if (isDoorOpen == 0)
                {

                    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                    loader.load( 'model/flame.stl', function ( geometry ) {

                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xa80306, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
                    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );    
                    mesh.position.set( 0.145, -0.3, -0.29);
                    mesh.rotation.set( 0 , 0, Math.PI / 2 );
                    mesh.scale.set( 0.05, 0.05, 0.05);
                    mesh.castShadow = true;
                    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                    scene.add( mesh );
                    } );

                    //console.log("Panic 0");
                }       


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you want to show only one mesh at a time based on some condition. If that is the case, one possible solution is give a name to your mesh before adding to the scene and remove the old door based on its name before adding the new one. For example

`mesh.name = "openDoor"; 
scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("closedDoor"));
scene.add( mesh )`

Hope it helps.